# How to append numbers in a specific range to a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, append, visual-prolog

I'm trying to append some numbers to a list, these numbers is in range from `X` to `Y` where X is the lower bound and `Y` is the upper bound, and then save these generated numbers to a list.
I tried this:

```
domains
    list=integer*.

predicates
    nondeterm generate(integer,integer,list).
    nondeterm append(integer,list,list).

clauses
    append(X,[],[X]).   
    generate(0,0,[]).
    generate(X,X,[]) :-
            write("The Upper And Lower Numbers Are The Same\n").
    generate(X,Y,[X|T]) :-
            X<=Y,
            N=X+1,
            A=N+1,
            append(N,T,Z),
            generate(A,Y,Z).

goal
    generate(1,4,Result).
```

But when I test the goal it gives me "No Solution".
What am i doing wrong?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: You should tag the question with [visual-prolog] I guess.

Comment: Do a trace and see what happens on each recursive call to `generate(A, Y, Z)`. You'll probably see an issue with the recursive case. The logic, at first glance, doesn't seem to make any sense with `X` being incremented (`N = X + 1`) then that result also being incremented (`A = N + 1`).  You then call `append(N,T,Z)` on a home-made append (be careful: standard prolog already has an `append` although I don't know if Visual Prolog does, and it's not the same as yours), but `T` isn't instantiated. I suspect this isn't at all what you intended.

Comment: @lurker Thank you for your clarification, i tried to call the built-in appending method but it didn't work, so is this home-made method true or what ?, and i'm incrementing in (N=X+1) to add the next number in range to the list and the incrementing that number (A=N+1) to call the function with it again. Sorry but what do you mean by " T isn't instantiated" ?

Comment: The built-in `append` requires all elements to be lists. Your append will only take a term `X` and make a single element list out of it, `[X]` and requires the second argument be an empty list `[]`. It is very limited and doesn't really do much. *`T` isn't instantiated* means `T` has no value (at the time you call `append`). Your `append` will instantiate `T` to the empty list every time (not sure if that's what you intended).

Comment: @lurker No it is not what i intended at all. thank you very much for your assistance. But i only want to append a number to a specific non-empty list, if i added this  'append(X,T,[X|T])' where 'T' is any non-empty list, will that work?

Comment: That will not work since you can't "reinstantiate" `T`. If you want to prepend a number to a list `T`, just type `[N|T]`. You don't need append. If you want this to be part of a new variable, use, for example, `T1 = [N|T]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
?= findall(X,between(1,4,X),L).
L = [1, 2, 3, 4].
```

Bye

P.S.: For a pure implementation of between/3 see:
http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/blog/docs/05_run/05_frequent/advanced/arith.html

Comment: The OP is using Visual Prolog. Do you know if Visual Prolog has those pre-defined predicates?

Comment: I see `findall` there but not `between`.

Comment: `between` is not an ISO predicate, and some Prolog's don't have it. For example, GNU Prolog doesn't have `between`, either. It doesn't mean there's "something wrong" with the language. Although Visual Prolog is very off-standard in many ways besides, which makes it very unappealing from a pure Prolog perspective.

Comment: @lurker: GNU does have `between/3`. You must be using a very old version. And it is part of the [Prolog prologue](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#between). So while not ISO, this is as close to ISO as something non-ISO can get.

Comment: If your Prolog system doesn't have between/3 you can copy paste the code from the link I gave in the answer or any other code that does the same. You cannot use the source of SWI-Prolog for another Prolog system so easily, since it implements between/3 natively.