# Prolog Pure Implementation of findall

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a list of elements 1 to N.

I saw this post below showing how to do that: [How to append numbers in a specific range to a list in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34409508/how-to-append-numbers-in-a-specific-range-to-a-list-in-prolog)

But I need to a way to create a pure version of findall, does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't necessarily need to use the solution from this post you can use this:

```
range(E,E,[E]).
range(S,E,[S|L]):- S < E, N is S+1, range(N,E,L).
```